# How to get a row by condition using group by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get amounts for each currency that user has. There're 3 different tables that contain all the data about users money transactions: `money_incomes`, `money_outcomes` and `withdrawal_requests`.

So I want to get the result like:

```
currency_id: amount(money_incomes - (money_outcomes + withdrawal_requests))
```

But for the first time I'm trying to get amounts from each table that will group by `currency_id`:

```
SELECT
       coalesce(max(money_income.amount), 0) money_income,
       coalesce(max(money_outcome.amount), 0) money_outcome,
       coalesce(max(withdrawal_request.amount), 0) withdrawal_request,
       currencies.code currency
FROM (SELECT max(user_id) user_id,
             sum(amount) amount,
             currency_id
      FROM money_incomes
      GROUP BY currency_id) money_income
         FULL JOIN (SELECT max(user_id) user_id,
                           sum(amount) amount,
                           currency_id
                    FROM money_outcomes
                    GROUP BY currency_id) money_outcome
                   ON money_income.user_id = money_outcome.user_id
         FULL JOIN (SELECT max(user_id) user_id,
                           sum(amount) amount,
                           currency_id
                    FROM withdrawal_requests
                    GROUP BY currency_id) withdrawal_request
                    ON money_income.user_id = withdrawal_request.user_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = money_income.user_id
LEFT JOIN currencies ON currencies.id = money_income.currency_id
GROUP BY currency;
```

I'm expecting the following result:

```
currency_id | money_income | money_outcome | withdrawal_request
```

It works well for money_incomes table, but I have to use aggregate functions in `SELECT` and that's the point why I could not get correct result, so full joins in this case return the same structure because of grouping.

So I need something not to use aggregate functions in SELECT, but to get needed row from JOINs results.

**UPD:** current structure and expected result

current structure of all tables:

```
+--+-----------+-------+-------+
|id|currency_id|user_id|amount |
+--+-----------+-------+-------+
|1 |1          |1      |1000.00|
|2 |3          |1      |1000.00|
|3 |1          |1      |3.00   |
+--+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Expected (at least) result:

```
currency_id | money_incomes_amount | money_outcomes_amount | withdrawal_requests_amount
```

Expected great result:

```
currency_id | amount
```

Where amount is: `money_incomes - (money_outcomes + withdrawal_requests)`

**UPD2:** dbfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mqDJgY4Bxv8yWAgowneu1W/2

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Sample data a little short. Provide data for each table and more than 1 user id in each, they do have to be the same. Also provide the expected output for that data. Additionally table description(s) (ddl) would be useful.

Comment: @Belayer I've added link to dbfiddle

Comment: also I've already added the expected result at the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that there has to be income before there is outgoing or withdrawal so income table should always have same or additional currencyid inside , compared to the other two

```
with mit as (
  select currency_id as c, sum(amount) as amt from money_incomes group by currency_id
),
mot as (
  select currency_id as c, sum(amount) as amt from money_outcomes group by currency_id
),
wrt as (
  select currency_id as c, sum(amount) as amt from withdrawal_requests group by currency_id
)

select mit.c, mit.amt - COALESCE(mot.amt,0) - COALESCE(wrt.amt,0)
from 
  mit
  LEFT JOIN mot on mit.c = mot.c
  LEFT JOIN wrt on mit.c = wrt.c
```

Comment: yes, you're right, there is no withdrawals or outgoing money before income, so it works perfectly. Thank you!